# Java regular expression for decimal ranges separated by a delimiter

Tags: java, regex

I have a input field that I want to validate.This input is used to describe a range. The input can take values of the form `x-y` or `x,y` . `x` and `y` can be decimal numbers like 101.22-135.33 or 101.22,135.33. I am planning to use regular expression to check for the validity of this range field. Can someone provide with the appropriate regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want this:

```
(\d+\.\d+)[-,](\d+\.\d+)
```

The code:

```
String n1 = "125.6,11.2".replaceAll("(\\d+\\.\\d+)[-,](\\d+\\.\\d+)","$1");
String n2 = "125.6,11.2".replaceAll("(\\d+\\.\\d+)[-,](\\d+\\.\\d+)","$2");
System.out.println(n1);
System.out.println(n2);
```

prints:

```
125.6
11.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
^\\s*[=-]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\\s*(?:[,-]|and)\\s*[=-]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$
```

PS It won't accept `.50-.75` but will accept: `0.50-0.75`