# Why my regex is failing for single digits but working for double digits?

Tags: regex

I have the requirement to validate a String containing two numbers separated by a *dash*`(-)` or a *comma*`(,)`. Valid values are :

1. `23.98-34.76` *or* `23.98,34.76`
2. `23-34` *or* `23,34`
3. `5-6` *or* `5,6`

I have the following regex which is a slight modification of the answer that I received [here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20044115/1168904). It is covering the 1st and 2nd case above but not the third case involving single digits only.

The modified regex String that I am using is :

```
(\d+\.?\d+?)([-,])(\d+\.?\d+?)
```

Where did my regex go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct regex should be like this:

```
(\d+(\.\d+)?)[-,](\d+(\.\d+)?)
```

i.e. if there is a period then it is always followed by 1 or more digits.

Otherwise in your regex it will also match strings like `123.,789.`

Comment: After second thoughts your solution is more appropriate and better than mine, I will delete mine and +1 for you.

Comment: @anubhava can you please explain the regex a little bit. What is the capture in the middle doing ? Specifically the `(\.\d+)?` part?

Comment: Yes that is what I added in my answer that `(\.\d+)?` means `if there is a period then it is always followed by 1 or more digits` so that you cannot validate input like **`123.,789.`**

Comment: Also `(\.\d+)?` can also be written as `(?:\.\d+)?` to make it a **non-capturing group** intention is to group not to capture.

Comment: @anubhava What is the usefulness of a non-capturing group?

Comment: @Inquisitive: That **non-capturing group** is mostly used when you are doing some replacements using these **captured groups** and don't want to waste any group #. Using **non-capturing group** we can still have group # as 1, 2 rather than 1, 3